# Vert.x WildcardPermissionBasedAuthorization .match returns false

Tags: vert.x

I'm having trouble understanding how `WildcardPermissionBasedAuthorization` works [(docs)](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/auth/authorization/WildcardPermissionBasedAuthorization.html)

The following code returns **false**, which as far as I know means that the user is not authorized, though I would expect at least one of these 'or' authorizations to match the wildcard one of "t*"

```
User user = User.create(new JsonObject().put("username", "testUser"));
user.authorizations().add("", PermissionBasedAuthorization.create("test"));
user.authorizations().add("", WildcardPermissionBasedAuthorization.create("t*"));

OrAuthorization or = OrAuthorization.create();
or.addAuthorization(PermissionBasedAuthorization.create("t"));
or.addAuthorization(PermissionBasedAuthorization.create("te"));
or.addAuthorization(WildcardPermissionBasedAuthorization.create("t"));
or.addAuthorization(WildcardPermissionBasedAuthorization.create("te"));
or.addAuthorization(WildcardPermissionBasedAuthorization.create("te*"));

or.match(user); //is false
```

What I'm trying to achieve is give my user access to anything that starts with 't', and then in my handler assert whether the user has access to 'te'

thanks,

Fil

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out you can put a wildcard for an entire colon-delimited section only, like
"newsletter:edit:*"

[from here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-auth/blob/4.0.3/vertx-auth-common/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/auth/authorization/impl/WildcardExpression.java)